# Woocommerce Moving Review Below add to cart breaks button

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, jquery, hooks

Trying to add the reviews on a site below the add to cart button in woocommerce. Both these snippets of code do it:

```
add_action('woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', create_function( '$args', 'call_user_func(\'comments_template\');'), 14);

function woocommerce_template_product_reviews() {
    woocommerce_get_template( 'single-product-reviews.php' );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'comments_template', 50 );
```

The add to cart will now not work unless you complete a review.

Is there a way to do this with hooks?

Or will I need to use jQuery to clone and move the review code to where I want it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button` is inside the `<form>` element for adding items to the cart, but the reviews form is its own form, and you can't have one form inside another form.

You need to pick a hook that's not inside a `<form>` element. `woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form` seems to be the closest that's still outside a form.

Comment: yeah great that worked and makes sense.